# Camera Calibration in Video Frames (mp4) without Chessboard or any marker

Tags: computer-vision, feature-extraction, camera-calibration, surf, orb

I am new in the field of computer vision and try to get the extrinsic camera parameters from video frames.

I have the intrinsic paremeters of my camera (focal length etc.). However, to analyse my video stream I would like to get the exttrinsic camera paremeters.

Is this possible via e.g SURF/ORB? anyone has experience with it? and can recommend some tutorials, preferably in Pyhton.